# sharepoint regional settings are differenet from server settings

Tags: windows-server

how to force sharepoint 2010 to use hosting server settings

just as date and time

i have problem in hijri date , sharepoint's date is different from server's date (hijri only)

any ideas please ?

Answer (score 1):

Tried using Site Settings -> Regional Settings within the site collection's top-level site?

Comment: thnx for ur reply , yes i tried this by adding hijri adjustment , but this didn't fix the problem